# starting container process caused: exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to Dockerize my FastApi app, but it crashes with this error right after I run the command:

```bash
docker-compose -f local.yml up -d
```

Can anyone help me, please?

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6.11-alpine3.11
ARG MYSQL_SERVER
ARG POSTGRES_SERVER
ENV ENVTYPE=local
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash
ADD /compose/scripts.sh $APP_HOME
ADD /requirements/$ENVTYPE.txt $APP_HOME
RUN chmod +x scripts.sh

RUN ./scripts.sh
RUN pip install -r /home/app/web/$ENVTYPE.txt; mkdir /log;

COPY /src/ $APP_HOME
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

**local.yml file**:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    env_file: .env
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/nginx.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
       - "${EX_PORT_NGINX:-8030}:80"
    volumes:
       - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  core:
    env_file: .env
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/core.Dockerfile
      args:
        MYSQL_SERVER: ${MYSQL_SERVER:-}
        POSTGRES_SERVER: ${POSTGRES_SERVER:-}
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - ./src:/home/app/web/
    logging:
       driver: "json-file"
       options:
          max-size: "5m"
          max-file: "10"
```

Error:

```
Cannot start service core: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Comment: Do your environment.txt files have uvicorn as a dependency? Have you tried inspecting the built image afterwards to see whether uvicorn is available inside the container? (i.e. is it a build issue or a runtime issue). You can this by creating a shell inside the container and using `ls` etc. to inspect the contents.

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes mate, I have the uvicorn as dependency, I think is a runtime issue.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I add commands `poetry run` and it's works.

```
services:
 api:

  ...

  command: [
    "poetry", "run",
    "uvicorn",
    "app:main",
    "--port", "5000"
  ]
```

Comment: I am using poetry and this worked out for me, thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain why poetry solves this?

Comment: Brilliant! The poetry command runs from the environment where the packages were installed

Answer (score 6):

You need to pip install fastapi and uvicorn:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn

COPY main.py ./

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Or include in requirements.txt:

```
fastapi>=0.68.0,<0.69.0
pydantic>=1.8.0,<2.0.0
uvicorn>=0.15.0,<0.16.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to Dockerfile,
`ENV PATH /home/${USERNAME}/.local/bin:${PATH}`, 
before
`RUN pip install -r /home/app/web/$ENVTYPE.txt; mkdir /log;`, 
by replacing `${USERNAME}` with the container user.

If you don't know the current user, add `RUN echo $(python3 -m site --user-base)` somewhere in the Dockerfile. Then copy the output of that `echo` to replace `/home/${USERNAME}/.local`.